# tasker to turn on do not disturb when plugged into charger

Tags: tasker, silent-mode

I'm trying to use Tasker to turn on the do not disturb mode in android 6.0 marshmallow.  I used to use tasker to make my phone go silent when I plugged in my charger cord every night, and turn off silent when I unplugged the cord in the morning.  Tasker broke I think with Lollipop when we lost our silent mode.  Now with Marshmallow we have do not disturb, but tasker can't seem to trigger it and/or has no access to "do not disturb."  I set up a profile (state/power/any) and a "task" (audio/do not disturb/all) but it does nothing when I plug in my power cord.  Can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: Your Tasker version?

Comment: There very latest in play store.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because you designed the action not to do anything but let Android disturb you, as usual. Here's what each entry corresponds to under Audio → Do Not Disturb:

- None: silences all sounds, including alarms - Total Silence
- Priority: silences sounds except for certain calls or notifications - Priority Only
- All: this *effectively ends Do Not Disturb mode*
- Alarms: silences all ringtones & vibrations except alarms - Alarms Only

<sub>(Content partially derived from the article: [Silence your device with "Do not disturb"](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6111295?hl=en)  - by Elena)</sub>

Comment: Tasker's Notification Access Service must be enabled for this action to work. Tasker suggests this at the first time setup of that action. Otherwise, enable it from Settings app -> Notifications -> Notification access -> tick Tasker.